# Not able to receive FCM notifications when app is in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am working with FCM notifications. My notifications are working perfectly when the App is in background but not able to receive a notification when the app is in foreground. I tried almost everything but not working. Notifications are not received when App is in foreground.

Manifest.xml:

```
       <service
        android:name=".Notification.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".Notification.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Code(FirebaseMessagingService) :

```
           @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    try {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        handleDataMessage(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }


    Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

}

private void handleNotification(String message) {
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        // play notification sound
        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
    } else {
        // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
    }
}

private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("body");
        boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
        String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
        JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

        Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
        Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
        Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
        Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
        Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage("iGrab", message, timestamp, pushNotification);
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();


        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Splash.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

            // check for image attachment
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
            } else {
                // image is present, show notification with image
                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: the only thing that matters here is the payload you send with the notification. Please share it

Comment: @TimCastelijns not understand what you are saying

Comment: I feel so stupid, worked after I removed exported="false" from service declaration in the AndroidManifest file. Happy coding everyone!

Answer (score 1):

FCM support two types of messages:

- Notification message
- Data message

If server send **Notification message** then it automatically displays a notification on system tray.

> Use notification messages when you want FCM to handle displaying a
>   notification on your client app's behalf. Use data messages when you
>   want to process the messages on your client app.
>
> FCM can send a notification message including an optional data
>   payload. In such cases, FCM handles displaying the notification
>   payload, and the client app handles the data payload.

And the point is in your case:

> Notification messages are delivered to the notification tray when the
>   app is in the background. For apps in the foreground, messages are
>   handled by a callback function.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options